# When linking multiple UIButtons to a single IBAction, how can I change the default 'sent event' in consecutive UIButtons?

Tags: swift, xcode, button, action, ibaction

I'm sorry, I know this is so elementary but I'm having trouble finding out how to change the 'sent event' in a UIButton. I have two buttons and have simply connected them to my .swift file as Outlets so I can change their image, but have also created an IBAction from one of the buttons and then click-dragged the second button to the same IBAction.

When creating the IBAction, the dialog pops up where I can select the sent action... in this case I want 'touch down'. But when I drag and drop the second button to this same IBAction, that option isn't available and I can see in the connections inspector that the sent action has defaulted to 'touch up inside'... how do I change that to match the desired 'touch down' for this IBAction? Thanks for your help!

```
import UIKit

class LoginScreen: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var loginBubble: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var registerBubble: UIButton!

    @IBAction func userBubblePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let userBubble = sender.tag

        print(userBubble)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh! I finally found it... thought I'd answer my own question in case any other newbies are also struggling with this ;)

1) Right-click on your object (button) so you see all the connections.

2) Left-click on the little circle to the right of the sent action you want and then drag THAT onto your IBAction in your code.

3) Delete your original connection that you don't want anymore.

Easy as pie haha.

[image]

Comment: I tried this in Xcode 11 and could not get it to work :\